# detect free fonts and delete non licensed ones

Tags: windows, fonts

I have a PC with a lot of fonts. Some might be commercial free or not. Is there any way to detect the fonts? I would like to delete the fonts that are not free.

The ultimate solution would be to re-install windows and to check in the future all the fonts that would be installed.

PS: I would also like to keep the default fonts (from windows, office..)

Comment: Maybe you want to install a virtual machine, install office inside, and then compare? I guess, if you go to the fonts folder, and order by the date, you will easy find the manually installed fonts.

Comment: I guess, neither Windows nor Office bring "free" fonts.

Comment: on that pc i have more than 6000 fonts, and I need to uninstall the ones that are not licensed (the ones that are installed from the web...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontExpert shows a field named "Embedding Rights", this helps with my problem...
I can uninstall the fonts that require a license.

Comment: Does this solve your problem?  If so, you can accept your own answer to indicate that it is solved.  It would be useful, though, to expand your answer to help others with the same problem.  If it doesn't solve your problem, add this information to your question and update it with your current status to better enable people to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7, Go to Control Panel > Fonts. From there, it should list all of the installed fonts.

If you have a downloaded .ttf file and installed, locate it and remove it as normal from the Fonts folder.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I want to detect the unlicensed fonts

Comment: I tried Google on that several times, it's next to impossible to detect unlicensed fonts. So, sorry. :(

Comment: i've been searching too... and that's why i've asked, thought someone might know